# Gearman , php extension problem : Class 'GearmanWorker' not found in .. using terminal but works on browser

Tags: php, linux, unix, ubuntu, gearman

I've installed gearman on ubuntu 10.04 recently and installed it's pecl extension. Now , when I run a php file in the browser that contains :

```
$client = new GearmanWorker();
die(var_Dump($client));
```

I get `object(GearmanWorker)#1 (0) { }`

but when running the a real worker file in terminal (by root) , I get this:

```
sudo php worker.php
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/imagick.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'pcntl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'GearmanWorker' not found in /home/ME/public_html/try/worker.php on line 3
```

The worker code :

```
#!/usr/bin/php 
<?php $worker= new GearmanWorker();
$worker->addServer('127.0.0.1');
$worker->addFunction("reverse", "reverse_fn");
while (1) {
    print "Waiting for job...\n";
    $ret = $worker->work();
    if ($worker->returnCode() != GEARMAN_SUCCESS)
        break;
}
function reverse_fn ($job)
{
    $workload = $job->workload();
    echo "Received
 job: " . $job->handle() . "\n";
    echo "Workload: $workload\n";
    $result = strrev($workload);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i ++) {
        $job->status($i, 10);
        sleep(1);
    }
    echo "Result: $result\n";
    return $result;
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Do `var_dump(get_include_path())` both in CLI and via CGI. They might differ.

Comment: sorry , I don't understand what you mean , but I'm installing php as an apchae module

Comment: it actually got installed using virtualmin panel

Comment: Type `php --ini` at your command prompt to see which php.ini your PHP CLI uses. Make sure Gearman is enabled in that php.ini.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Type `php --ini` at your command prompt to see which php.ini your PHP CLI uses. Make sure Gearman is enabled in that php.ini.

Answer (score 3):

using `locate php.ini`
in my ubuntu laptop show 2 results:

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

add both `extension=gearman.so` into 2 php.ini file
then restart php and gearmand working now.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install the gearman job server and libgearman

   apt-get install gearman-job-server libgearman-dev
2. Install the pecl extension

   apt-get install php-pear php5-dev
   pecl install gearman
3. Open the correct php.ini file and add `extension=gearman.so` at the end.