# gearman doBackground() not working with php

Tags: php, yii, gearman, worker, producer

i running on my local system with ubuntu 12.04 64 bit , PHP 5.3.10  , gearman 1.1.5 .
following code

```
print gearman_version() . "\n";
```

throws php warning

> PHP Warning:  Module 'gearman' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Also i built yii console app WorkerAdminCommand.php using

```
<?php
class WorkerAdminCommand extends CConsoleCommand {

public function run() {

    $gmworker = new GearmanWorker();
    $gmworker->addServer(); // also tried with $gmworker->addServer('127.0.0.1:4730');
    $gmworker->addFunction("getMyFunc", array($this, "getMyFunc"));
    print "Waiting for job...\n";
    while ($gmworker->work()) {
        if ($gmworker->returnCode() != GEARMAN_SUCCESS) {
            echo "return_code: " . $gmworker->returnCode() . "\n";
            break;
        }
    }
}

public function getMyFunc($job) {
     echo "start \n";
  // long task 
     echo "\n end \n";
}
```

}
?>

And AdminCommand.php

```
<?php

class AdminCommand extends CConsoleCommand {

public function run($args) {
    $gmclient = new GearmanClient();
    $gmclient->addServer();

    echo "Sending job\n";
    $data =  $args[0];
    $result = $gmclient->doBackground("getMyFunc", $data);

    # Check for various return packets and errors.
    switch ($gmclient->returnCode()) {
        case GEARMAN_WORK_STATUS:
        list($numerator, $denominator) = $gmclient->doStatus();
        echo "Status: $numerator/$denominator complete\n";
        break;
        case GEARMAN_WORK_FAIL:
        echo "Failed\n";
        exit;
        case GEARMAN_SUCCESS:
        echo "Job process successfully\n";
        break;
        default:
        echo "RET: " . $gmclient->returnCode() . "\n";
        exit;

    }
    echo $result . PHP_EOL;
}
```

}

?>

run worker 
php job_entry.php workeradmin
Waiting for job...
run client 
php job_entry.php admin arg1
this gives me error

> PHP Error[2]: GearmanClient::doBackground(): send_packet(GEARMAN_COULD_NOT_CONNECT) Failed to send server-options packet -> libgearman/connection.cc:430

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try this

```
 $gmworker->addServer('127.0.0.1','4730');
```

Comment: what is solution for 
`PHP Warning: Module 'gearman' already loaded in Unknown on line 0`
this error .

Answer (score 1):

Type php --ini at your command prompt to see which php.ini your PHP CLI uses. Make sure Gearman is enabled in that php.ini. src [Gearman , php extension problem : Class 'GearmanWorker' not found in .. using terminal but works on browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428014/gearman-php-extension-problem-class-gearmanworker-not-found-in-using-te)